# A program to find prime numbers stops unexpectedly

Tags: c++, for-loop, numbers

I wrote a very simple program to find prime numbers upto a certain range specified by the user. But I encountered a problem. The program simply stops printing out prime numbers when it reaches a composite number. I tried to see why it stops but I simply can't understand what is wrong with it probably because I am new to programming. Anyway, here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int y;
    int range;
    cout << "Please enter the range. \n";
    cin >> range;
    for (y = 2; y <= range; y++)
    {
        int result;
        for (int x = 1; x < y - 1; x++)
        {
            int prime = y - x;
            if (y%prime != 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                result = 0;
            }
        }
        if (result != 0)
        {
            cout << y << " is a prime number. \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `result` might be used without being initialized

Comment: You should initialize result to a non-zero integer, int result = 1;

Comment: For this task (print all primes below some limit) you almost certainly want to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes (or some variant thereof) rather than trial division.

Comment: You can tidy up the body of the inner loop by using `if (y % prime == 0) { result = 0; break; }` since you don't need to continue checking once you know it is a composite number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Brian Gradin points out, the only problem that I see is that you should initialize result to a non-zero integer.

```
int result = 1;
```

Only after this initialization can you make a valid check after the for loop, whether result has changed to zero.

Without initialization, any access to the value of this variable results in undefined behaviour.

EDIT:

For completeness I should add others' suggestions that the more standard way of doing this would be:

```
for (y = 2; y <= range; y++)
{
  bool isPrime = true;

  // The following loop should be changed to loop through the Sieve of primes
  for (int x = 2; x*x < y ; x++) // You need to loop only till sqrt(y)
  {
    if (y%x == 0) // if you found a factor
    {
      isPrime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( isPrime )
  {
    cout << y << " is a prime number. \n";
    // and add this to the sieve of primes.
  }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the original code will work, once this change has been made.  +1

Comment: @AvZ, please, accept this answer, if it helped, so others could see that this question has an answer already. And to thank the answer's author, of course :) (I'm not the answer's author)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int y;
    int range;
    int result;
    int prime;
    cout << "Please enter the range. \n";
    cin >> range;
    for (y = 2; y <= range; y++)
    {
       result=1;
        for (int x = 1; x <= y - 1; x++)
        {
             prime = y - x;
            if (y%prime != 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                result = 0;
            }
        }
        if (result != 0)
        {
            cout << y << " is a prime number. \n";
        }
    }
}
```

i have change your forloops limit statement..!!

```
 for (int x = 1; x <= y - 1; x++)
```

and have change your declarations to the top:

```
int result=0;
    int prime;
```

Comment: I see what you did there, but it may be helpful to explain for OP or others

Comment: Please, initialize `result` to something, it makes me nervous.Something other than zero.

Comment: Like I said - I see what he did.  But simply posting code isn't helpful.

Comment: @BrianGradin: i have added the explanations..!!

Comment: You didn't test this did you? Will `result` ever be anything other than `0`?

Comment: Thanks I got it. I realized that I had to reinitialize the value of result each time the loop ended so it can print the prime numbers.

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    int y;
    int range;
    cout << "Please enter the range. \n";
    cin >> range;
    for (y = 2; y <= range; y++) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x < y - 1; x++)
    {
        int prime = y - x;
        if (y%prime == 0)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    if (result != 0)
    {
        cout << y << " is a prime number. \n";
    }
    }
    }

Comment: @SajadLfc, Did you try... well, I don't know... running it? It doesn't work. And it can't work even in theory. We use `result==0` as a condition for checking if current number is a prime number. And you never initialize it to anything but zero. And you never initialize it in the beginning of the first loop.

Comment: This answer is still wrong. `result` needs to be initialized inside the outer loop or the logic only works once.

Comment: @SajadLfc, and now you "borrowed" and idea from Abhishek Bansal's answer, but still got it wrong. Your code won't work. And you're asking the author to accept it? With two exclamation marks? Good luck...

Comment: @Blastfurnace : absolutely..!! i have re-edited..!! thank  you for pointing out

Comment: @FreeNickname : i do made mistakes..!! and i accept it..!! but the author said he got it from my answer..!! so i asked him to accept it..!!